# how to change the string with decimal and hyphen into int

Tags: python, string, int

I am grabbing IP addresses from a site and part of the result looks like this.

> 192.168.1.1\t12345\t12345\t2013-05-14\t2013-05-14\n192.168.1.1\t98765\t98765\t2013-05-14\t2013-05-14

And of course the complete result have a lot of IP addresses. I'm trying to change that particular string into int so that I can get the length. I've tried

```
length = int(string, 16)
```

but it's giving me **invalid literal for int() with base 16** error. How can I change it into int?

Comment: You're grabbing IPs, but want the length of an int, and you're trying to treat your string as hex... Nope - I have no idea what you want... Try explaining in another way?

Comment: Sorry for the bad explanation. Actually i want to grab not only the IP but all the other values including the dates. I'm using socket to receive the data so I need the length to grab accordingly. Hope this explains.

Comment: Errr, so you just want to know that you should request 46 bytes then ? (as that is the size of each line above...) (if the last one does indeed have another `\n` there)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the length of the whole string you can just do `len(string)`. If you want to get the number of IP addresses, then you have to split by `\n` and then get the length of the returned list.

```
len(string.splitlines())
```

Comment: A bit more robust to use `somestr.splitlines()` instead

Comment: @jordan jambazov I tried using len(string) but it somehow reformat the result string and it will make it harder for me to process the data.

Comment: `len()` just returns an integer, it shouldn't reformat any string. Just curious, why do you need the length and how do you use it?

Comment: I'm using socket to receive the data. So I need length to grab the data accordingly. Actually I previously used this method to retrieve another data without any error. I can't seem to figure out what went wrong this time. Does it have to do with decimal and hyphen?

Comment: Modify the server to send data of fixed size. Then make the client receive the data with the same size constant and concatenate. It seems error-prone to me. However, if you really want to, do it this way: `int("asda".encode('hex'), 16)`

Comment: I modified the server and received the data with same size and it's working now. Thanks a lot